# Total number of red black tree arrangements

Tags: complexity-theory, binary-trees

Consider a list of *n* integers.

And assume we take each integer from this list sequentially and add it to a red-black tree.

Then for the *n!* permutations of the list how many red-black tree arrangements are there in total?

N.B: Some permutations result in the same arrangement.